# How to initialize a dynamic memory array with a single value in one line of code?

Tags: solidity, arrays

How can I create and initialize the single-value dynamic memory array.. inside the function call `acceptsArray(...)`?
Possible to create it and initialize in one line?

```
function acceptsArray(uint[] memory _a){
    doSomething();
}

function sendArray(uint x){

    // CAN THESE THREE LINES BE REDUCED TO A SINGLE LINE?
    uint [] memory c = new uint[](1); 
    c[0] = (_candidates[i]);
    acceptsArray(c);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now unfortunately the only way is to create a helper function that allocates an array and initializes, which has obvious limitations.

There are however plans to make dynamic array initialization easier in the near future: [Array literals should be convertible to both dynamically-sized and statically-sized arrays #11879](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/11879).